# Want to diaplay tabbar and listview in my launch activity

Tags: android, xml, listview, tabbar

```
I want to display the tab bar and listview but when my main activity launched then my tab bar gets hided... so tell me what is the problem in my xml or my src file.
```

My problem is: My tab bar is not showing and only listview is showing on the full screen.

Here my lisview appears first and behind that my tab bar slightly visible.

```
Main Activity:(Here I am displaying tab host)

    package com.example.testlist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;

    public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener{


        /*******************************/

        //Test for tab bar
        TabHost tabHost;
        /*******************************/

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            /*setContentView(R.layout.list_view_layout);

            ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        */

            setContentView(R.layout.layout_tab_bar);
            // Get TabHost Refference
              tabHost = getTabHost();

              // Set TabChangeListener called when tab changed
              tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

              TabHost.TabSpec spec;
              Intent intent;

               /************* TAB1 (home)************/
              // Create  Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeTab.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);

              //Add intent to tab
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              /************* TAB2(alerts) ************/
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);  
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              /************* TAB3 (newsletters)************/
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              /************* TAB4(calendars) ************/
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab4.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);  
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              /************* TAB5 (more)************/
              intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab5.class);
              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Fifth").setIndicator("")
                            .setContent(intent);
              tabHost.addTab(spec);

              // Set drawable images to tab
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homeicon);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alert_small_icon);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newsl);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_calendar);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.more_big);


              // Set Tab1 as Default tab and change image   
              tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);


        }
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {


        }
    }



HomeTab.java:(this class loads the content of first tab)
```

This class loads the content for the home tab where the contents related to home tab appears but my tab bar gets hided here.

```
    package com.example.testlist;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.R.anim;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class HomeTab extends Activity{

        MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
        Context context=HomeTab.this;

        String optionName[]=new String[] {"Alerts","Events","Newsletters","News","Parent Info","Logins","Parent Teacher Interviews","Flexi School LunchOrder","Contact US","Kool Content"};
    //  String text2[]=new String[] {"sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4","sub1","sub2"};

        //int image[]=new int[] {R.drawable.alert_small_icon,R.drawable.events,R.drawable.newsletter,R.drawable.newsletter,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24,R.drawable.arrow_24};
        int imageArrow[]=new int[]{R.drawable.right_arrow};

        ArrayList<ListModel> mylist=new ArrayList<ListModel>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.list_view_layout);

            ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            getDatainList();

            listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(context, mylist));

            listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        }

        private void getDatainList() 
        {

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)

            {
                ListModel li=new ListModel();
                li.setOptionName(optionName[i]);
            //  li.setImage(image[i]);
                li.setImageArrow(R.drawable.arrow);

                mylist.add(li);
            }

        }




    }

layout_tab_bar.java(This class displays the tab host and used in Main Activity)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
            >
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </TabHost>


listview_layout.xml:
This file shows how the listview is added:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Header  Starts -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <!-- Logo Start -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menuimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/menuicon_big" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"

            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Header Ends -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stbernard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/stbernard" />

    <!-- <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp" >
    </ListView> -->
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>


single_row.xml:

This file shows how the content inside listview appears for each item




    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

     <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rel">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageviewArr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <View android:id="@+id/testView"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_Options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you declare the height of the `content` to fill the parent here

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

that's why the `tabs` is being overlapped by the `content`, what you need is `android:layout_weight`, so you need to change it to this

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

`android:layout_weight` will fill all the remaining space of the `parent view` so it won't overlap with each other